# Clarification for public key while signing initial transaction

Tags: corda

I need clarification from API doc reference,
If I am signing transaction based on legal identity key then it works fine.

If I am signing transaction by generating fresh public key and send it to acceptor then it throws exception - The Initiator of CollectSignatureFlow must have signed the transaction

Here as per below doc, we can use public key of legal identity Or can generate public key for signing transaction

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your issue is as follows:

- When adding the required signers to the commands, you're using your standard identity
- When signing the transaction, you're using a fresh public key, which doesn't correspond to the identity listed in the commands
- The counterparty can't match your signature with the fresh public key to your standard identity listed as a required signer, and therefore throws a `SignaturesMissing` exception

Instead of creating a fresh public key manually, you should be use the `SwapIdentitiesFlow`: https://docs.corda.net/api-identity.html#swapidentitiesflow.